# html5 video element has any bug? it does not keep playing the content after few hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, video

I need to play a video content for 24/7, its an idle movie keep playing as loop. 
But after playing few hours when there is no activity in the PC, suddenly the video stop playing as loop. It was tested with Google chrome/Canary with latest version available in Windows 8.1 64-bit machine.

As following:

```
<video id="mediaplayer" 
       autoplay="autoplay"  
       poster="/images/blackscreen.jpg"  
       type="video/webm"
       loop="true"></video>

<script>
var video_idlea = 'http://localhost/loop.mp4';
function video_idle() {
  $('#mediaplayer').prop('loop', true);
  $('#mediaplayer').attr('src', video_idlea).show();
  mediaplay_video= document.getElementById('mediaplayer');
  mediaplay_video.play();  
  mediaplay_video.onended = function(e) {
    console.log('>>> Playing finished: ', e);
  };
}

function video_play_any(input) {
  $('#mediaplayer').prop('loop', false);
  $('#mediaplayer').attr('src', input).show();
  mediaplay_video= document.getElementById('mediaplayer');
  mediaplay_video.play();  
  mediaplay_video.onended = function(e) {
    console.log('>>> Playing finished: ', e);
    video_idlea = 'http://localhost/idle.avi';
    video_idle();
  };
}

video_play_any('http://localhost/loop.mp4');
</script>
```

Am i doing anything abnormal here? it should keep playing infinite isnt it? or am i doing anything wrong here? Please advise.

Comment: Memory leaks and what not are common in browser applications that use multimedia.  When your video has been running for an hour or so, consider reloading the page upon next loop and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @Brad: i have ovserved it for 14 hours now. I did a screen record with processor, memory usage and loop file, i saw the system had no issue with RAM, CPU it had enough space. But still it failed to loop after playing for 14 hours. It must be a BUG in Google Chrome/Canary. It would be nice if someone with knowledge report this issue in bug tracker cause its happening only with Chrome/Canary, when i used VLC or Gstreamer it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Brad: i solved this temporary by removing this into this: `<video id="mediaplayer" 
       autoplay="autoplay"  
       poster="/images/blackscreen.jpg"  
       type="video/webm"
       loop="false"></video>`, and in `video_idle()` i recalled `video_idle()` on end event trigger. This must be a BUG, please report someone, my knowledge about Chrome/Canary is low so therefore someone with knowledge should report this for fixing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use javascript code
like this

```
document.getElementById('mediaplayer').play();
 document.getElementById('mediaplayer').pause();
 document.getElementById('mediaplayer').currentTime = 0;
```

because in jquery code video tag element will not work,